# Locate a Cell using row and column value and increase the Cell's value by 1 on button click

Tags: vba, excel

I have just learned the the basics in `VB` and I wonder if someone can help me with coding my Excel worksheet to locate a cell using row and column value and increase the located cell's "value" (the number contained in the located cell) by a specific integer (say, +1) on button click. I have looked in the FAQ's to no avail. If you feel that I have missed it, please provide me the link so I can get to it. I already learned the basics of coding in `VBA` but if you could just elaborate the advanced codes, it would be very much appreciated.

To explain further, 1 have designated the range as `5x5 cells` (5 cells long, 5 cells wide, starting with cell A1). The row number will be inputted in Cell `A7` as "4" and  the column number in `A8` as "3". Once the button is clicked, the cell will be located, and it will add a value to the `cell = + 1`. As output, the cell "C4" should have the number "1" in it because it's were the column number and row number intersected.

Also, the value in the column# cells are to be transferred to the row# cell, meaning the value of cell `A7` will be "3" and `A8` will be "blank". It's because I would be using the values in the column# cells to be my row# cells values for the next inputs.

Any reactions, comments, answers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time in reading. :) (I'm sorry if I can't provide a rough image example as the site won't allow me to post images yet.)

Comment: So what are you stuck on in particular at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this for you .. do this in your button

```
Sub SetAddr()
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim sCell As String    

x = ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Value
y = ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Value
sCell = StrRange(y, x)

'assumed the cell is blank
If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range(sCell)) Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(sCell).Value = ActiveSheet.Range(sCell).Value + 1   
End If

End Sub

Function StrRange(ByVal nRow As Single, ByVal nCol As Single) As String
Dim sC As String
Dim nC, nRest, nDivRes As Integer

sC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
nC = Len(sC)

nRest = nCol Mod nC
nDivRes = (nCol - nRest) / nC

If nDivRes > 0 Then StrRange = Mid(sC, nDivRes, 1)
StrRange = StrRange & Mid(sC, nRest, 1) & Format(nRow)
End Function
```

I'm sure you can do the rest ....

Comment: Thank you so much. I have yet to try the code but I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: You're welcome .. it's already tested on Excel 2007

Comment: Hello matzone, I've tried the code you've given and it worked like a charm :) However I ran into a couple of "limitations" of the code. I must admit it was my mistake to not indicate it in my question earlier. 1.) Whenever a combination was already entered, it doesn't add up the number inside the cell (it's just "1") and 2.) Can you suggest additional codes so i can enter multiple x and y values? Say enter 2 x values and 2 y values? The result would have been like 1x1y, 1x2y, 2x,1y, 2x2y. Thank you again for the help! :)

Comment: @Marcus .. it's update only for number 1 .. for multi offset, why dont you use looping to set all matrix cell ? .. or you want it in your way like random ?

Comment: Well, to be perfectly honest with you, I just crashed-course myself in coding VBA :). I have yet to learn how the loop() method works or how it's set up. But thanks for the code you provided, I guess I'll just go from there. To answer your question, I already have a set of numbers I wanted to plot, it's just that the code you provided (I think) is only good for 26x26 cells (since the alphabet is only 26). The scope of my planned graph is actually for 50x50 cells. with 5 x-y coordinates to consider per input. Again, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Marcus .. good luck ! I'm sure you can do it !

Comment: hello again. I took your advice and studied the loop method. it worked great :). But yet again, I stumbled into another limitation. Whenever a a cell with two letters is selected (AA1, AB1, etc..) it shows an error "Application-defined or Object-defined error". Can you please help me with this error? I think it's the only thing avoiding me from completing my worksheet. It would be great if you can help me again sir.

Comment: @Marcus .. i give this for you .. hope this help .. from now you must do it by yourself .. ok ?!

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll figure out the rest from here on end. Really appreciate your help! :) Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("wksht").Range("$a$n").Value = Worksheets("wksht").Range("$a$n").Value + m
```

Where wksht is the worksheet, a is the desired row, n the desired column, and m the desired incrementation factor. I should note that you are going to want to check the value to make sure it's a number, you can never trust the end user to make the right entry.

Found here: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=165438

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in answering my question. :)